# maven-release-plugin reported not threadsafe during parallel execution

Tags: maven-release-plugin

We have a multi-module maven project in which I'm [enabling parallel execution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3). But when I run the build with the `-T` option (e.g. `mvn -T 2C clean package install`), the following warning is reported in the build logs:

```
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
[WARNING] * Your build is requesting parallel execution, but project      *
[WARNING] * contains the following plugin(s) that are not marked as       *
[WARNING] * @threadSafe to support parallel building.                     *
[WARNING] * While this /may/ work fine, please look for plugin updates    *
[WARNING] * and/or request plugins be made thread-safe.                   *
[WARNING] * If reporting an issue, report it against the plugin in        *
[WARNING] * question, not against maven-core                              *
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
[WARNING] The following plugins are not marked @threadSafe in test-service:
[WARNING] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1
[WARNING] ****************************************************************
```

As you can see, I have already upgraded to version of `maven-release-plugin` to `3.0.0-M1`, which is the latest version available in my company's nexus repository.

I also checked other documents for [parallel execution and list of plugins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3), but could not find a version for this specific plugin which is thread-safe. Please can anyone advise which version is thread-safe or what else I can do resolve this issue ?

Comment: This must be added by the project itself. Add an issue / pull request with the changes: https://github.com/apache/maven-release/